# Send Modbus RTU request via TCP with Netcat and catch the response

Tags: linux, modbus, netcat, rs485

Let's say I have a Modbus RTU temperature controller connected to a device that reads TCP packets from a network and sends the payload from said packets to the temperature controller over RS485. If I wanted to test such a setup by sending a Modbus RTU [Read Input Registers] request over TCP/IP using netcat on a Linux command line, what would be the full command for that, assuming that it is possible?

```bash
nc 192.168.0.5 2000   # ...what now?
```

Suppose that the following details apply:

---

- device address: 1
- function code: 3 (read input register)
- memory address: 1000H
- no. of registers: 1

---

- server IP address: 192.168.0.5
- client IP address: 192.168.0.4
- Port on server: 2000

---

I feel like I can listen for the response using netcat, also. Could I just do that with:

```bash
nc -l 3456
```

Would that be right? To send a request and log the response like this, I guess I would have to specify the port to send the request on as 3456 (or whatever). Is there a way to do that?

Especially, I'm confused as to how to turn a Modbus message like [01][03][1000H][01][CRC] into its bytes equivalent.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should it be of use to anyone, the answer to this question is:

```
echo -e -n '\x01\x03\x10\x00\x00\x01\x80\xCA' | nc 192.168.0.5 2000
```

-e allows the conversion of escaped chars 
-n prevents a newline character being appended

Listening for incoming messages using Netcat doesn't work, apparently because the individual Netcat process wants to make the TCP connection itself, otherwise it isn't interested in anything arriving at the specified port. Still, I am able to see the reply coming back from the slave using Wireshark, and have also written to registers and successfully controlled the device.

Answer (score 2):

You can send raw bytes with:

```
echo -e '\x04\x03...' | nc host port
```

> Especially, I'm confused as to how to turn a Modbus message like [01][03][1000H][CNC] into its bytes equivalent.

That would be:

```
echo -e '\x01\x03\x10\x00...' | nc host port
```

I'm not going to calculate if for you because I see no point in doing something like this other than for fun.

You'll have to put all parts of the Modbus frame together, just google it. The most difficult part is to calculate the CRC at the end of the frame. I guess that's what you mean by CNC?

If you struggle I would suggest you try something like [QModMaster](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/#:%7E:text=QModMaster%20is%20a%20free%20Qt,all%20traffic%20on%20the%20bus.). Look at the raw data with menu *view*<kbd>►</kbd> *Raw Data* and use those bytes.

Note that other than building the frames, QModMaster would be able to send them too and even listen for and receive responses. That should be your one-stop-shop for Modbus. You can also find many other tools like pymodbus, libmodbus, minimalmodbus and even command line tools for Windows and Linux.

If you edit your question to present a fair reason why you need to use `nc` (obviously other than for fun) maybe I can try to offer some more help.

I could not find any references on using netcat to send and/or receive Modbus frames. I'm not sure if that's because I did not search long enough or because it is pointless... Maybe it's both.